# SELECT CASE WHEN - Not performing index seek

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

Im using SQL server 2017 and I have a query which does a select and joins from a few tables. When I look at the query plan I notice that the SELECT CASE WHEN part of the query is performing an index scan and its getting back one row but having to iterate through many more. Has anyone come across this scenario? Not been able to get it to perform an index seek. Essentially I look up an account but this account could be in many services and therefore the SELECT CASE WHEN is to go through this and get me back the right ones. Due to this its also granting more memory than it needs to. Planning to run this many times so it might not be an issue now but as I run it more it will become a problem.

Please can anyone shed some light on my errors / understanding?

Statistics are all up to date.

Example snip from my query. The myview is basically a select with a few of the columns from the table.

```
use DB_test
go

declare @acID int
set @acID = 28


select r.OT_ID as ID,
    aclID.aID as aID,
    r.fDName as DName,
    r.fDA as DA,
    r.fExp as Exp
from myviewDomaR r
 join (
    select
        CASE WHEN a.P_OAcc_ID = 9 then a.OAcc_ID
            ELSE a.P_OAcc_ID
        END as aID,
        a.OAcc_ID as actACID
    from myview acc
)
 aclID on aclID.actACID = r.Acc_OAcc_ID
 where exists (
    select 1
    where aclID.aID = @aclID
)
```

[image: Query Exec Plan]

Comment: Please show your full query including `WHERE` clause

Comment: We would need more information in order to help you, but you should keep in mind that SQL needs to build an execution plan that will be good whatever value is specified in the where clause. Meaning that if you expect SQL to come with an index Seek because of that specific value in your where clause, it will not as the plan needs to be reusable for the same query but with a different value in the where clause. (That could go into another branch of the CASE. If you want to see if this is your case, just stick an "option (recompile)" in your query and see if that changes the plan shape.

Comment: Hi Martin.
use DB_test
go
--Removed at symbol on purpose below 2 lines
declare acID int
set acID = 28


select r.OT_ID as ID,
    aclID.aID as aID,
    r.fDName as DName,
    r.fDA as DA,
    r.fExp as Exp
from myviewDomaR r
 join (
    select
        CASE WHEN a.P_OAcc_ID = 9 then a.OAcc_ID
            ELSE a.P_OAcc_ID
        END as aID,
        a.OAcc_ID as actACID
    from myview acc
)
 aclID on aclID.actACID = r.Acc_OAcc_ID
 where exists (
    select 1
    where aclID.aID = @aclID
)

Comment: Please use the [Edit question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/265927/edit) link and add this to the Q not as a comment

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please consider reading the [ask] portion of the help centre and possibly have a look at [mcve]. Please also consider posting either the full screen shot of the Index Scan (with predicated) or posting the whole execution plan via [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) (Brent Ozar).  Without the whole picture we won't be able to help you with an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't automatically transform non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expressions to enable using an index.

You can try changing this:

```
CASE WHEN a.P_OAcc_ID = 9 then a.OAcc_ID ELSE a.P_OAcc_ID END = @aclID
```

to something like:

```
(a.P_OAcc_ID = 9 and a.OAcc_ID = @aclID)
or
a.P_OAcc_ID = @aclID
```

Comment: Thanks David, Are you saying to replace the CASE WHEN completely so change the CASE WHEN statement?select
        CASE WHEN a.P_OAcc_ID = 9 then a.OAcc_ID
            ELSE a.P_OAcc_ID
        END as aID,
        a.OAcc_ID as actACID
    from myview acc

Comment: THE CASE LOGIC IS Required as I'm trying to search the account and relate to different scenarios. The issue is it seems to do an index SCAN rather than a seek as you can see the estimated rows is way too much. Not sure whether you are suggesting I try and remove the SELECT case completely David? Cheers

Comment: It seems the scan happens due to the case because SQL server doesn't drill down enough so instead its pulling all the rows and then applying the logic where in theory it should go I need to find this account and then do the case. Interesting....

Answer (score 0):

Have decided to re-write the query so lets consider this resolved.

THE SELECT CASE WHEN did not really have a predicate or true or false condition and therefore wasn't able to utilize the index properly.